# SAS ODS can't print reports in the printer

Tags: sas

I have a problem in my intership and that's my supervisor told me to check some SAS code where they print reports, they told me that the program is all correct and functions perfectly in windows 7. When they migrated to windows 10, the same program made report files, but didn't print physical documents, so the problem is that they got tons of files, but zero printed papers, so I need to check if there's a new setting the program needs for the program to print automatically.

Comment: What research have you done to diagnose the problem ? Have seen any error messages in the SAS log ? What SAS statements in the 'perfect' program are used to create the print jobs or files ? Is the program supposed to create files and then issue a system command to print them ? Are the system print queues full of unprinted jobs ?  Can you get a simple sample program to print ? Can you print from other applications such as Excel or Word ?

Comment: @Richard Thank you for your response, I just came back from checking the computer. The man who was using the code to generate reports showed me that he was using two computers, one with winXP and another with win10. Both having the same SAS program, the first one creates a file and prints it physically. The second one, on the other hand, just generates a file. About the system print queue, if you mean the printer icon located in the right part taskbar, it didn't appear. Sadly, I forgot to check if in the windows10 computer can print from other applications.

Comment: @Richard Maybe I need more information from my supervisor.